# Error al consumir WebApi y probarla en localhost

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webapi

Tengo una WebApi, donde hago una consulta a Sql Server, en otros controladores no hay problema, se hace correctamente, pero en éste me salta el siguiente error

> An error has occurred. 
>   Multiple actions were found that match the request: Get on type
>   WebApiFacturador.Controllers.ConexionController DatosEmpresa on type
>   WebApiFacturador.Controllers.ConexionController 
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    en
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext) en
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext) en
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) en
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

Éste es mi código

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApiFacturador.Datos;

namespace WebApiFacturador.Controllers
{
    public class ConexionController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Conexion
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET: api/Conexion/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/Conexion
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/Conexion/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Conexion/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
        SqlConnection miConexion = new SqlConnection("data source = snare.arvixe.com; initial catalog=****; user id=****; password=****");
        [HttpPost, HttpGet]
        public string DatosEmpresa(int idempresa)
        {
            try
            {
                if (miConexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    miConexion.Open();
                }
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT idEmpresa, [Status], Empresa, RFC, svrFacturador, usrFacturador, bddFacturador, pwdFacturador, cuantosFolios, comunFac, llave FROM logins where idEmpresa = '" + idempresa + "'", miConexion);
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Conexion datos = new Datos.Conexion();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                List<Conexion> LstRazon = new List<Datos.Conexion>();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
                da.Fill(ds, "logins");
                //da.Fill(ds, "CrmCustomersEmails");
                //Data Row llenarlo con el data set 
                DataRow DR;
                DR = ds.Tables["logins"].Rows[0];
                //Si el usuario existe, extrae sus datos
                if ((idempresa == int.Parse(DR["idEmpresa"].ToString())))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //Traer los datos del usuario logueado
                        datos.Status = int.Parse(reader["Status"].ToString());
                        datos.Empresa = reader["Empresa"].ToString();
                        datos.RFC = reader["RFC"].ToString();
                        datos.svrFacturador = (reader["svrFacturador"].ToString());
                        datos.usrFacturador = (reader["usrFacturador"].ToString());
                        datos.bddFacturador = (reader["bddFacturador"].ToString());
                        datos.CuantosFolios = int.Parse(reader["cuantosFolios"].ToString());
                        datos.ComunFac = (reader["comunFac"].ToString());
                        datos.IdEmpresa = int.Parse(reader["idEmpresa"].ToString());
                        datos.llave = Guid.Parse((reader["llave"].ToString()));
                        LstRazon.Add(datos);
                    }
                    miConexion.Close();
                    var JsonLogin = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LstRazon);
                    return JsonLogin;
                }
                else
                {
                    miConexion.Close();
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                miConexion.Close();
                return "Error" + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

y éste mi archivo de RouteConfig

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Me parece que el error no está en tu código de sql , si gustas comentá todo el codigo dentro de la funcion e intenta de nuevo. Creo que el compilador no sabe cual de los ACTIONS (funciones) de tu controlador usar, no puede distinguir el parametro y nombre que le estás pasando. puedes pegar todo tu controlador o al menos las funciones con sus data anottations? tienes dos POST o GET con un int como parametro? tambien te recomiendo que si el action solo regresa datos y no recibe datos mas que el ID, le quites el [HttpPost]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te aconsejo que pongas un **[RoutePrefix("Api/NombreDelController")]** arriba de tu **public class NombreDelController: ApiController** así ya sabes que en cada peticion hacia ese controller la ruta por default siempre será **"localhost:TuPuerto/Api/NombreDelController" + "TuMetodo"**

Cuando vayas a recibir un dato en tu método **Get** por lo general siempre se reciben **FromUri Ejemplo : "localhost:TuPuerto/Api/NombreDelController" + "TuMetodo?parametro=valor"** y cuando sea un método Post van **[FromBody]**(Te lo dejo de tarea)

También puedes añadir otro fragmento a la ruta que configuras por defecto al inicio del controller añadiendo **[Route("Fragmento")]** por encima de tu método Ejemplo : **"localhost:TuPuerto/Api/NombreDelController" + "Fragmento?parametro=valor"** esto para evitar que el nombre real de tu método no quede expuesto como tal

Deberías utilizar un solo verbo por método en tu controller para que no tengas problemas y podrías separar la lógica de tu método principal para que identifiques mas rápido los errores que llegues a tener y utilizar un objeto de tipo **HttpResponseMessage** para generar una respuesta mas elaborada de tus servicios

Si no logras llegarle al servicio con la ruta **"localhost:TuPuerto/Api/TuController/TuMetodo?parametro=valor"** podrías intentar quitando la palabra **"Api"** de la url ya que en ocasiones al crear el proyecto y no utilizar el **[RoutePrefix("")]** toma por defecto a partir de **"/TuController/TuMetodo?parametro=valor"**

Te dejo algo que podría ser de ayuda respecto a rutas y mejores prácticas https://medium.com/@schneidenbach/restful-api-best-practices-and-common-pitfalls-7a83ba3763b5

Comment: Encontré algo raro ahora que se solucionó, cuando agrego dos parámetros más al método, funciona perfectamente, y dejo 1 o 2 parámetros, y me salta el mismo error que puse en mi pregunta,¿ eso a que se deberá?

Comment: Quizá se deba a la forma en la que estas llamando el servicio, un ejemplo de enviar dos parámetros seria de la siguiente manera **localhost:TuPuerto/Api/TuController/TuMetodo?parametro=valor&parametro2=valor2**, si recibes un objeto en tu metodo la llamada al método seria igual